# How to call json array in ng-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

i want to call json array on button click. i want to list the details on button click.

this is the format

```
$scope.menuOptions = [
       ['New Folder', function ($itemScope) {
        }],
        null,
        ['Copy', function ($itemScope) {

        }],

        ['Paste', function ($itemScope) {

        }],
        ['Delete', function ($itemScope) {



        }]
    ];
```

i want something like this,

```
$scope.accc = function() {
$scope.menuOptions();
}
```

to call the above json. am new to angular js. Help me please .i don't know this is a valid question or not.

Comment: What does "call JSON array" means?

Comment: the above json will call on right mouse click and i want the same on button click

Comment: @stark you need to print 'New Folder', 'Copy',etc right? on button click

Comment: i want to call $scope.menuOptions , to get the menu list

Comment: yes i want to print

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.callItem = function(itemName, arguments) {
    for (let itemID in $scope.menuOptions) {
        var item = $scope.menuOptions[itemID];
      if (!!item) {
        if (item[0] == itemName) {
                item[1].apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        }
      }
  }
}

$scope.callItem('Copy');
```

In Angular you to like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuOptions" ng-click="item[1]()">
        item[0]
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or like this:

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuOptions" ng-click="callItem(item[0])">
        item[0]
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would recommend you to use a nother data structure based on objects instead of arrays. For example like this:

```
$scope.menuOptions = {
       'New Folder' : function() {},
        'Copy' : function() {}
}
```

Comment: can i call directly?

Comment: To call it directly out of angular you need to add it into the website scope

Answer (score 0):

you need to tweak your JSON a bit, you can set the 'New Folder' as an object key instead of array. see the following example:

```
/* Javascript: */
$scope.menuOptions = {
    'New Folder': function ($itemScope) {
        console.log('New Folder Created',$itemScope)
    },
    'Copy': function ($itemScope) {},
    'Paste': function ($itemScope) {},
    'Delete': function ($itemScope) {}
};

$scope.clickedMe = function(action_name,value){
    menuOptions[action_name](value);
}
```

and use it in your html template something like this

```
/* HTML: */
<button ng-click="clickedMe('New Folder',myelement)">New Folder</button>
<button ng-click="clickedMe('Copy',myelement)">Copy</button>
<button ng-click="clickedMe('Paste',myelement)">Paste</button>
<button ng-click="clickedMe('Delete',myelement)">Delete</button>
```

using NG-REPEAT to render buttons:

```
<button ng-repeat="(key,value) in menuOptions" ng-click="clickedMe(key,other_elem_here)">
    {{key}}
</button>
```

Comment: No...there is only one button , when i hit i want to display the arry in menu shap

Comment: this ways its generic, you can display it however you want. and when you are creating use the edit i just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Menu object array as below:

```
 $scope.menuOptions = [
           {
                label:'New Folder', 
                action:function ($itemScope) {
                   alert('New Folder');
                }//End of function
            },
            {
                label:'Copy', 
                action:function ($itemScope) {
                    //function body
                    alert('Copy Copy');
                }//End of function
            },
            {
                label:'Paste', 
                action:function ($itemScope) {
                //function body
                alert('Paste');
                }//End of function
             },
            {
                label:'Delete', 
                action:function ($itemScope) {
                    //function body
                    alert('Delete');
                }//End of function
            }
        ];
```

UI:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuOptions" ng-click="item.action()">
        {{item.label}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Trigger any function out of ng-repeat on Button click :

```
//that will triger 'New folder' function
<button ng-click="menuOptions[0].action">{{menuOptions[0].label}}</button>
```

Comment: i want to trrigger only on button click